# Why does this function break in Powershell?

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to replicate this Self-Elevating script in Powershell, but as a function instead of as an entire script so to break up the code for better flow.  The original code can be found here.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2010/09/23/a-self-elevating-powershell-script.aspx

However, when I rewrite the same code as a function, it errors out dramatically. Any idea what is causing the fault? This is the new, erroneous code.

```
function SelfElevation 
{

# Get the ID and security principal of the current user account
 $myWindowsID=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
 $myWindowsPrincipal=new-object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal        ($myWindowsID)

 # Get the security principal for the Administrator role
 $adminRole=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator

 # Check to see if we are currently running "as Administrator"
 if ($myWindowsPrincipal.IsInRole($adminRole))
{
    # We are running "as Administrator" - so change the title and background color to indicate this
$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition + "(Elevated)"
$Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = "DarkBlue"
$Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = "White" 
clear-host
}
 else
{
# We are not running "as Administrator" - so relaunch as administrator

# Create a new process object that starts PowerShell
$newProcess = new-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo "PowerShell";

# Specify the current script path and name as a parameter
$newProcess.Arguments = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition;

# Indicate that the process should be elevated
$newProcess.Verb = "runas";

# Start the new process
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($newProcess) 
# Exit from the current, unelevated, process
  Stop-Process -Id $PID
}
}

 # We call the self elevation here
 SelfElevation

 # Run your code that needs to be elevated here
 Write-Host -NoNewLine "Press any key to continue..."
 $null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
```

This code works fine as I truncate it, right up until the part where it hits Start $newProcess, and it simply does not seem to like the new process being executed in a function. However, why?

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: What is thte value of $PID ? Have you tried removing the "Stop-Process"  call?

Comment: Still errors. In the new window, I see a quick rush of red error characters but I can't see it before it closes. How do I keep the new instance open?

Comment: "Errors out dramatically" and the error(s) are...?

Comment: All I see is a large row of red letters in the new instance before it closes. I can't seem to keep the new instance open to see what the error is - how could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix for "white spaces in path" problem and also additional code to set new powershell process path to actual script location
And another fix of error when script is located at mapped network drive

```
#region Self-Elevating
Set-Location ( Get-Item $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path ).Directory

$myWindowsID = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$myWindowsPrincipal = new-object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal( $myWindowsID )
$adminRole = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator

if ( !$myWindowsPrincipal.IsInRole( $adminRole )) {

# This fixes error wen script is located at mapped network drive
$private:scriptFullPath = $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
if ( $scriptFullPath.Contains([io.path]::VolumeSeparatorChar )) { # check for a drive letter
$private:psDrive = Get-PSDrive -Name $scriptFullPath.Substring(0,1) -PSProvider 'FileSystem'
if ( $psDrive.DisplayRoot ) { # check if it's a mapped network drive
$scriptFullPath = $scriptFullPath.Replace( $psdrive.Name + [io.path]::VolumeSeparatorChar, $psDrive.DisplayRoot )
}

}
[string[]]$argList = @( '-NoLogo', '-NoProfile', '-NoExit', '-File', "`"$scriptFullPath`"" )

$argList += $MyInvocation.BoundParameters.GetEnumerator() | % { "-$( $_.Key )", "$( $_.Value )" }
$argList += $MyInvocation.UnboundArguments

Start-Process PowerShell.exe -Verb Runas -WorkingDirectory $PWD -ArgumentList $argList -PassThru
Stop-Process $PID
}
#endregion
```

Thanks Keith Hill and Randy in Marin

Answer (score 3):

The arguments your script takes is likely to be slightly different than what Powershell.exe takes.  Try this approach:

```
[string[]]$argList = @('-NoProfile', '-NoExit', '-File', $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
$argList += $MyInvocation.BoundParameters.GetEnumerator() | Foreach {"-$($_.Key)", "$($_.Value)"}
$argList += $MyInvocation.UnboundArguments
Start-Process PowerShell.exe -Verb Runas -WorkingDirectory $pwd -ArgumentList $argList
```

Comment: Thank you for this code as it solve "white spaces in path" problem!